# Check how many of every string is in a string (simplified)

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

So i need to count how many times a string is inside a string. I saw someone earlier posted a more complex version, but my assignment requires i cant use libraries and have to do it manually.

Below i create a program that will find the start of every short string in a long string.

Lets assume the

```
string longword = "bigbigbiggbigbigbiig;
string shortword = "big" ;
for (int i = 0; i < 20;)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if(longword[i]==shortword[j])
                    {
                        i++;
                    }


                }
                cout << (i-(shortword)+1) << ", ";
            }
```

My problem is the output below sometimes it reads words like iii consecutively, or ggg consecutively. You can see it works, until it gets to the end the output it starts at `0,3,6,10,13,15,17` The problem is it works correctly up until 6 then it reads 7 and puts the wrong starting position for the words there.

What am i doing wrong? And the problem is generally i cant use advanced libraries and code for this as instructed.

Thanks!

Comment: Split the problem in pieces. First write a function that finds a substring inside a string and returns its position. Once you have it (and tested it), your problem simplifies quite a bit.

Comment: BTW, this question could also be worded, "Finding the number of occurrences of a substring within a string." Using that wording might help you find search results.

Comment: "... my assignment requires i can't use libraries..." + `string longword` etc. seems to contradict that, or were you granted latitude by your instructor to use `std::string`, part of the standard library? If your class allows using just `std::string` *and its members* the latter should help *immensely*, in particular [`find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the performance is not a concern, you can start with the following code

```
string longword = "bigbigbiggbigbigbiig;
string shortword = "big" ;
for (int i = 0; i < longword.size(); ++i)
{
    bool found = true;
    for(int j = 0; j < shortword.size(); ++j)
    {
        if(longword[i + j]!=shortword[j])
        {
            found = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) cout << i << ", ";
}
```

If you are concerned with performance, you can search Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm or similar topics on string search.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm allowed to mend the program..

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
char longword[] = "bigbigbiggbigbigbiig";
char shortword[] = "big" ;
int i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0;
while(longword[i]!='\0')
{
    j=0;
    k=0;
    while(shortword[j]!='\0')
    {
        if(shortword[j]==longword[i])
        {
            k++;
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        else
            j++;
    }
    if(k==3)
        l++;
}
cout<<l;
}
```